# Fighting Apache hacking attempts with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

In a given PHP web application, mod_rewrite is often used to simplify URLs and make it easier for PHP to provide the desired content. But on the other hand, it can open up opportunities for hacking attempts, especially when written by someone (like myself) relatively new to mod_rewrite. Consider a simple example, not code, just the conversion itself, using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file to read user agent data, and add it into the URL as GET data:

Safari users: `example.com/page -> example.com/page?browser=safari`

Chrome users: `example.com/page -> example.com/page?browser=chrome`

IE users: `example.com/page -> example.com/page?browser=ie`

If an Internet Explorer user wanted to see the Chrome version, he or she could send a request for the page with the GET data already there, which would be updated as follows:

Hacker:

`example.com/page?browser=chrome -> example.com/page?browser=chrome?browser=ie`

Sure, it's a contrived example, but the idea's still there. If you have mod_rewrite strip out all GET data first, does that break stuff later? More importantly, can GET data be allowed from certain sources (like the site's app) but not from others (like a browser, wget, curl or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

To strip out all browser(client) supplied query strings you can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]+)\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

**PS:** Due to use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` this will allow query parameters to be added internally by other rewrite rules not using `R` flag.

Comment: What about selective query stripping, like allowing queries from an app but not from a browser or command line tool?

Comment: This will just block query strings from browser or command line tools

Comment: I got that, but what if sometimes I want query strings allowed? The example was, if I built a mobile app for my site, and used the correct site request format within that app, I wouldn't need to mod_rewrite the URL at all. But that is only if it was my own app that was making the request. Can .htaccess mod_rewrite use that as a rewrite condition somehow?

Comment: ok check updated answer to have a check based on `%{HTTP_REFERER}`. Replace `domain.com` with your actual domain. But keep in mind `%{HTTP_REFERER}` can also be customized on client side.

Comment: Is there anything less hackable?

Comment: Np, there is no other way to detect whether a web request is coming from a browser OR being made by your own web page.